# Subtract columns in two dataframes to get differences in Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

Having two dataframes with same columns, I would like to create a resultant dataframe with the difference between the columns, having into account that the dataframes have a lot of columns (and rows).

I guess the approach is first doing an inner join, and then do a **"WithColumn"** with a **subtract** inside, but I don't know how to do this in an automated way for **a lot of columns**.

Example:

first dataframe:

| Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | colXX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.6 | ... | 1.8 |

second dataframe:

| Id | col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | colXX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 2.1 | ... | 2.1 |

Expected dataframe:

| Id | diff_col1 | diff_col2 | diff_col3 | ... | diff_colXX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.0 | 0.5 | ... | 0.3 |

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prepare the selection of the differences and then apply it to the resulting dataframe from the join.

```scala
val selection = 
    df1.columns.diff(Seq("Id"))
       .map(x => (col(s"df1.$x") - col(s"df2.$x")) as s"diff_$x")

val query = 
    df1.as("df1")
       .join(df2.as("df2"), Seq("Id"), "inner")
       .select((Seq(col("df1.Id")) ++ selection):_*)
```

Notice the alias on the dataframes in the join matching the names being used in the difference calculations.